# sql query takes much long time compared to next run

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, performance

I'm running a procedure which takes around 1 minute for the first time execution but for the next time it reduces to around 9-10 seconds. And after some time again it takes around 1 minute.

My procedure is working with single table which is having 6 non clustered and 1 clustered indexes and unique id column is uniqueidentifier data type with 1,218,833 rows.

Can you guide me where is the problem/possible performance improvement is?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the procedure.

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] (
        @HLevel NVARCHAR(100),
        @HLevelValue INT,
        @Date DATE,
        @Numbers NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
    )
    AS 

    declare   @LoopCount INT ,@DateLastYear DATE 


    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( list of columns )
    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ( list of columns )

    -- LOOP FOR 12 MONTH DATA
    SET @LoopCount=12
    WHILE(@LoopCount>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @LoopCount= @LoopCount -1 

            -- LAST YEAR DATA
            DECLARE @LastDate DATE;
            SET @LastDate=DATEADD(D,-1, DATEADD(yy,-1, DATEADD(D,1,@Date)))




                    INSERT INTO @Table1  
                    SELECT list of columns 
                        FROM Table3 WHERE  Date = @Date   
                    AND 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @HLevel='crieteria1' THEN col1
                        WHEN @HLevel='crieteria2' THEN col2
                        WHEN @HLevel='crieteria3' THEN col3
                    END =@HLevelValue



                    INSERT INTO @Table2 
                        SELECT list of columns 
                        FROM table4
                        WHERE  Date= @LastDate 
                         AND ( @Numbers IS NULL OR columnNumber IN ( SELECT *  FROM dbo.ConvertNumbersToTable(@Numbers)))

INSERT INTO @Table1
        SELECT list of columns 
            FROM @Table2 Prf2 WHERE Prf2.col1 IN (SELECT col2  FROM @Table1) AND Year(Date) = Year(@Date)



   SET @Date = DATEADD(D,-1,DATEADD(m,-1, DATEADD(D,1,@Date)));

 END 

  SELECT list of columns FROM @Table1
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Execution plan to give you an idea of what is happening with the query?  Also, the first time it runs, it will cache the execution plan in memory making it quicker to execute next time round.

Comment: Please show some code so we can have a look at what you are doing.

Comment: Is there any ways to add execution plans manually to speed up and it will be there for forever.

Comment: you can't force it to be there forever as SQL Server may remove it. Also, it's not the execution plan cache that offers the greatest improvement - it's having the data cached. And again, SQL Server can remove stuff from the cache after a while.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first time the query runs, the data is not in the data cache and so has to be retrieved from disk. Also, it has to prepare an execution plan. Subsequent times you run the query, the data will be in the cache and so it will not have to go to disk to read it. It can also reuse the execution plan generated originally. This means execution time can be much quicker and why an ideal situation is to have large amounts of RAM in order to be able to cache as much data in memory as possible (it's the data cache that offers the biggest performance improvements).

If execution times subsequently increase again, it's possible that the data is being removed from the cache (and execution plans can be removed from the cache too) - depends on how much pressure there is for RAM. If SQL Server needs to free some up, it will remove stuff from the cache. Data/execution plans that are used most often/have the highest value will remain cached for longer.

There are of course other things that could be a factor such as what load is on the server at the time, whether your query is being blocked by other processes etc

Comment: Some guesses. Run \\ CHECKPOINT \\ DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS() \\ after the first execution. If subsequent executions are still slow, then AdaTheDev is spot on. It's the cache.

So if the goal is to get the query to run quickly in all circumstances, more information is needed.

Comment: @Chingi - best thing you can do with the procedure is to rewrite it to get rid of the loop. Loops/cursors should generally be avoided if you want good performance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that stored procedure is recompiling repeatedly after some time. To reduce the recompilation please check this article:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/18/sql-server-plan-recompilation-and-reduce-recompilation-performance-tuning/