# Slow performance when using fully qualified name in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 for this issue.

In one of my apps, I need to refer to a table from another database. So I do a query:

```
USE Db1
SELECT * FROM Db2.dbo.Table1
```

It takes ~2 seconds for the query to complete even for a table with just 300 records. The delay is consistent, I ran it in Management Studio and hit Execute and the result is the same. I did this for around 10 times with consistent results.

Now when I run the query but this time running it in the context of the actual database:

```
USE Db2
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

There's virtually no wait time when the same results are returned.

Now the weird part is, when I go back to my first query, the delay no longer happens! And this behavior is reproduced every time I restart SQL Server.

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? Do you have any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You can find the answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049970/sql-query-takes-much-long-time-compared-to-next-run

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be an issue with caching. I tried the 1st query A LOT of times and it always had the same delay. All my queries when I'm on the 1st DB is always slow. But as soon as I run the query on the 2nd DB, everything is fast. It doesn't seem logical to always run the query on the 2nd DB before I run queries on the 1st DB.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured this one out. The Auto Close property for the database being referenced in the SELECT was set to True. I set this to False and the delay during the SELECT calls disappeared.

So what was happening was it was always starting up the database for every SELECT statement! I checked the Event Viewer and true enough, a log of the database starting up is there for every call.

To set this to false, I used Management Studio, right click on the Database, then go to Properties. In the Properties window, select Options and under the Automatic group, the first item is Auto Close. Set this to False.

See the link below for more information on the Auto Close property. It is set to True by default. Set this to False, and you should not encounter this problem.

[Auto_Close](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d91da3fe-e0f9-4597-b925-44df9e788953/autoclose)

Comment: I haven't run into this problem yet, but in case, I know the solution. Thanks for answering your question.

Comment: Certainly not true by default (maybe on your model db only?). This is an evil setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mystery here, and the fully qualified name plays no role at all.

The table data are cached in memory the first time you ask for them. Any subsequent calls will read the data from memory instead of reading them from disk. Additionally, SQL Server caches compiled execution plans and reuses them for new queries.

Each time you restart SQL Server you start with empty the memory buffers and execution plan caches so the first query you execute will be significantly slower.

In order to get meaningful results, you need to clear the buffer and execution plan cache using these commands:

- [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) will clean the execution plan cache, forcing new queries to be recompiled
- [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx) will clean the memory buffers, forcing SQL Server to reload data from disk

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it but when I ran the first query, I did that multiple times (around 10 times) with consistent result. So I don't think the caching of the query is the answer in my case.

Comment: What are the execution plans and statistics for the two queries when each is executed AFTER you clean the caches?

Comment: Checked the execution plans and statistics and it is the same? Hmm. I'm looking at the Cost values. Didn't matter whether I cleaned the caches. The results are the same, is there a specific statistic that you want me to check? but there's still a significant delay when I execute the first query.